# Poincaré lemma in infinite dimensions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, tag-removed

Hi everyone,

Is the Poincaré lemma true in infinite dimensions?

Here's a precise statement:

Let $X$ be a Banach (or maybe Hilbert) vector space, $U$ a simply connected open set in $X$. Is it true that every closed (smooth) $1$-form on $U$ is exact?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is, on convenient locally convex vector spaces. 
Convenient is a very weak completeness condition.
See 33.20 in:

Andreas Kriegl, Peter W. Michor: The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis. Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, Volume: 53, American Mathematical Society, Providence, 1997.[(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf)

Comment: And your book looks fantastic, thank you for that.